# Transfer characteristics of a Toshiba DMOS FET

Tags: fet, device-characteristics

I am looking at the [TBD62003A load driver](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/datasheet_en_20150724.pdf?did=29886), but it is very light on details about transfer characteristics.

Are there characteristics curves available from a similar device? Specifically, I want to know what will happen if there is a <150 μs pulse of 12 V while V<sub>GS</sub> is 3 V. What will the current peak at? Will the gate resistance limit it to under 1 A?

The closest I've found is in the [BSS-123](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bss123-d.pdf) datasheet.

Is is appropriate to scale/extrapolate from the BSS-123 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the Toshiba device I have settled to use the [TPL7401](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpl7407la.pdf) from TI with full characteristics provided.